# Collection of YA horror short stories late 80s early 90s called "Chills" or "Shivers"

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, young-adult, horror

I am looking for a series of books from the late 80's early 90's. There were at least 2 books in the series, called "Shivers" or "Chills". They were a collection of horror stories for Young Adults. I used to borrow them from my local library all the time as a teen; I am now 33 and have been searching in vain for these books for years.

One of the stories I remember the most was about a young boy who had to walk through either a builders yard or a lumber yard regularly in the dark. He used to imagine that there was a monster behind him and try not to run. One night the monster becomes real and the last thing the boy feels is its claws on his back and the story ends.

I read these in Britain so possibly they had a different name elsewhere.

Comment: maybe we're looking for the same series. i can't seem to find them. i remember 3 stories from my series. maybe we can compare notes? the first one i remember is about a boy who discovers a cave and enters it with a female friend. they find out it's actually an indian burial place and there is a huge white dog that lives in the cave and kills any who enter. also, there was another story about a boy and his friend who discover that their printer allows them to release monsters from their pictures online into real life. and the last one i remember is about goblins who hide under leaves on the gro

Comment: HI Jillian, you may be right, the stories you mention do ring a bell, I remember these as being pretty dark, they were not for younger children but teenagers, I can't remember if they were set in Brirain or the US, another tat I can recall is a guy out on the moors to take photos and he gets stuck in mud and something is after him! If you get anymore info let me know!

Comment: I remember taking out that book every Halloween from my school library! I think they're children stories though, cause I was able to read it in fourth grade! But now I'm desperately trying to find it too. I believe the cover of the book is black if I'm not mistaken

Comment: I remember the title of the book was in either red or green, I think that there was 2 of them, the original and then a sequal with more stories,I have tryed everywhere and am still searching!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I remember the same story and actually think I read two versions of the same/similar story. I know one version came from a short-story compilation called [*Lonesome Places*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lonesome_Places) (1962) by August Derleth (which I think I found in my grandparents house). According to Wikipedia there were only ever 2,000 or so copies, so I guess that makes it an unlikely match- but it was too similar not to mention (in fact, after re-reading it, I'm pretty sure it has to be a variation on this story)...

The story itself, [*"The Lonesome Place"*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lonesome_Place) begins with the narrator having to run an errand for his mom and cross a lumber yard and "the lonesome place" which becomes spooky when it gets dark (the Wikipedia summary is excellent, this one is not). The creature/monster that they imagine feeds on children's fear and basically becomes whatever horrible thing kids imagine it to be. In the end when the boys are older they hear about another boy having been allegedly mauled by a wild animal near the lonesome place and realize/believe that it was actually the monster born of their fear. (Again, I'm not doing it justice here.)

I love the internet! Just found the full text of an earlier version of ["The Lonesome Place"](http://www.unz.org/Pub/FantasticMysteries-1948feb-00114) by August Derleth as it appeared in *Famous Fantastic Mysteries*, February 1948.

ISFDB has a list of books that this story appeared in [here](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?91793).

Comment: This is the story! Thanks so much, it must have been republished in a later collection which I read, now I just need to figure out where.

Answer (score 7):

It is [Tales for the Midnight Hour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tales_for_the_Midnight_Hour) by J.B. Stamper. That particular story is called *The shortcut*. These were my favorite scary books in like sixth grade.

Comment: Interesting... _"This anthology horror series served as the precursor to various other similar works, including Scary Stories to Tell in the Dark and Scary Stories for Sleep-overs."_

Comment: The Tales From the Midnight Hour may just be it. The red script for the title looks like what I remember. But I don't remember there being so many stories per book. I remember like maybe 2 stories to a book and it was a "series" of 10 or so....../: hmmmmm......may have to do more digging.

Answer (score 6):

I can't identify the story itself, but it's possible it was [Goosebumps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goosebumps). In addition to short novellas, there were also a number of anthology books. The original books were published between 1992 and 1997.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that but I have checked the Goosebumps series before and it isn't those, I think it would have been earlier than this!

Answer (score 3):

There is the [Shivers series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shivers_%28novel_series%29), although none of the brief synopsis's on that link seem to match the story you described.

Comment: Hi, I have looked at the Shivers series and like the Goosebumps series mentioned by Phantom42 it would have been earlier than this, late 80's but possibly published earlier than that, thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

This could be one of the [Scary Stories to Tell in the Dark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scary_Stories_to_Tell_in_the_Dark).  The third book, called *Scary Stories 3: More Tales To Chill Your Bones*, was published in 1991.

[This site](http://www.scaryforkids.com/stories-to-tell/) contains synopses/the stories from the first two books, but not the third one.  The story you remember sounds like the type of thing that would have been in them.

Technically they're children's stories, not Young Adult, but given the suspense/horror factor, it's easy to mix them up...

Comment: Hi, thanks for that, I have already looked at these and and it wasn't what I was looking for! The search continues...

Answer (score -1):

Lorna, I believe it's called "*Fright Time*"! I can't believe it(though),because it took me so long to find it since my very first answer on here. I literally went through Google typing possible names of young adult horror book series. I typed in *Fright Night* and *Fright Time* popped up and I'm glad it did. Each book had 3 stories and I was looking at the description of one of them and it had the story with the ghost dog that I remembered and the cover art was what I remembered it looking like. Unfortunately, the books are no longer in publication and I have no idea if you can even buy them anymore. :( But at least my burning curiosity was satisfied. I hope this is the series you were looking for as it certainly was mine. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It would be great if you could mention some of the details you found that match between the question and the books/stories you found.

Comment: Hi Jillian, I have already looked at these and they are not the books I was looking for, I am glad that you have solved your mystery.

Answer (score -1):

The Derleth story is also in 'Nightfrights' ed. Peter Haining - might that be the collection?  I remember this in both hardback - green cover showing snarling wolf - and paperback - lurid cover with old man on it.  http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2323200.Nightfrights

I also think there was an earlier Haining hardback ghost anthology published late '70s, with a green cover and some excellent tales: but I can't remember its title and he edited so many....

Answer (score -1):

At first, I also thought this might be Goosebumps. Do you think this could be the Point Horror series? I remember reading them in the 1990s; most of the books were by American authors but there were a few books by British authors as well. I remember The Forbidden Game trilogy by L J Smith was published under Point Horror in the UK. Other authors I remember were Diane Hoh - she had numerous books in this imprint. Hope that helped, sorry if it's not what you're looking for though. All the best, Lily.